# Connect VM directly to external network in openstack

Tags: networking, juju, maas, openstack

I have installed openstack using MaaS and JuJu on Ubuntu 14.04 machines. I am using Neutron openstack for networking which is installed on a VM. I can assign a  floating IP to VM and ping it. However , I can not ping or access the VM if I connect it directly  to external network (not through the router).An idea if this scenario is supported? and what could be the problem?

Another problem is that the floating IP works with VM that has 10.04 OS , and It does not work if the VM instance has 14.04. Usually if I ping it I get Destination host unreachable
"Reply from 172.16.0.238: Destination host unreachable".

What I could not understand is that the IP 172.16.0.238 is for the VM, so how does it reply by "Destination host unreachable"

Thank you for help